# prompt is not working in rails4 send method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a hash map and am iterating the hash map and by passing the key and value to the send () ex:

```
 <%= ud.send(v["q_type"], k, Carmen::Country.all.collect { |country| [country.name, country.code]},{:selected =>v["answer"],:prompt=> "Select a Country"},:class=> 'form-control select2', :id=>'test')%>
```

select and k is select tag.

The prompt text is not adding to the dropdown.

Comment: Did you tried giving `:include_blank` instead of `:prompt`?

Comment: yes i tried that it didnt help

Comment: <%= ud.send(v["select, country, Carmen::Country.all.collect { |country| [country.name, country.code]},{:selected =>India,:prompt=> "Select a Country"},:class=> 'form-control select2', :id=>'test')%>